# JavaScript - How to know timeout is executed for a method which is running periodically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

In JavaScript, I have written a method and I am executing this method for every 5 mins.After 15 mins , I am stopping this call.

```
var tChk ;
tChk = setInterval("test()", 5*60*1000);
setTimeout("timeOut(tChk)", 15*60*1000); // 15 mins time out

function timeOut(tChk) {
    clearInterval(tChk);
}

function test() {
  console.log("test");
}
```

**How can I know whether my method is still executing or it expired because of timeout.** . Is there any option in Chrome Dev tools where it shows the list of methods queued for execution?

Thanks.

Comment: You are using console.log at every 5 min..so you can check if console.log is occuring after 15 minutes or not.

Comment: I have added the console log just for my reference . I want to know in production where you wont have such console logs.

Comment: you can maintain a bool bit to track if the timer is stopped or not, set the value false after clearing the interval `timerRunning = false;`. by default you can set this to true before starting the timer.

Answer (score 2):

```
function startTimer(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){ 
        var tChk = setInterval(test, 5*60*1000);
        var count=0;
        function test() {
            console.log("test");
            count++;
            if(count>10){
                clearInterval(tChk);
                resolve();
            }
        }
        function timeout(){
            clearInterval(tChk);
            reject('timeout');
        }
        setTimeout(timeout, 15*60*1000);
    })
}
startTimer().then(function(){
    console.log('count reached!');
}).catch(function(e){
    console.log(e);
})
```

There is no way to list the timer method with pure javascript.

Comment: The above is based on console log . But I want some other solution.

Comment: console.log is just a code example,you can replace with your code.